# Shorthand alternative to find

Tags: find, locate

Is there any alternative out there for `find` similar to `ag` and `ack`?

I'm really tired of having to type:

```
find some/app -iname "some_file*"
```

I much rather just type:

```
find "some_file*"
```

And have it search for the current folder and recursively in all subfolders.

Comment: Sweet. Can you direct me to some resource that explain how to create that script or function above? If you post that as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what functions or scripts are for. e.g.

```bash
myfind() {
    search="$1"
    shift
    find . -iname "$search" "$@"
}
```

The `"$@"` on the end allows you to still specify other find options if you want to.  Note, however, that `find` is quite fussy about the order of some options, some options only work if they come before the path (`.` in this case).

Some cause `find` to whinge about them being after a non-option argument.

e.g. `find . -iname "*.txt" -maxdepth 1` causes the following whinge:

> find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -iname, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.

AFAIK, there's no option to turn off these warnings...or if there is, it's not called `--quiet` or `--silent`.

Anyway, save the function above in a text file, e.g. `myfind.txt`. Then source it with:

`. myfind.txt`.

If you want it to be defined on every login, add the function definition to your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`, or source `myfind.txt` from them.

This assumes you are using a Bourne shell like `sh` or `bash`.  Note that some versions of `sh` may require the keyword `function` before `myfind` - e.g. `function myfind() { ... }`.  If you are using `csh` or `tcsh`, then...well...don't, switch to a Bourne shell.

Comment: This works, but it searches the whole file directory from the root like `locate` does. How do I get it to search the current directory and its subfolders?

Comment: If it's searching from `/` that would be because your current directory is `/`.  or maybe you have a symlink to `/`.    `find .` specifically means "start searching from the current directory"

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. Thx.

Comment: Ive been looking for a solution to converting `find . -iname "*searchterm*"` into a zsh function that just takes a shortened command and the term like `$ ff searchterm` and somehow this did it. Just noting that `shift` was critical as it wouldnt work without it. Ive been looking for this solution for a looong time. This was a win for osx/zsh/iterm!